# how to resolve boolean error while navigating back to home page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

I have three class in my app. Home, First and Second. I have used stack navigator to navigate between these classes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUAsI.png). From Home to First and coming back to Home is working fine but from Home to Second and coming back is throwing me an error. I searched a lot but didn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.[click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUAsI.png)

Comment: please, post the code of the three classes

Comment: sorry due to some restrictions I can't post the code here. To be more clear I would like to say I am not doing any operation in class first and second. Just going and coming back.